# Android App crashes on Android TV after running for a long time

Tags: android

TO quickly summarize my app its an simple app which loads a URL in webView and that url plays videos and some images in sequence.

Code :

```
WebView mWebView;
int mQuality; // Make sure to initialize this somewhere

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "testWake:wakeLockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    // Capture screenshot and send to the server

    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getScreenshotAsURI(); // Capture and send screenshot
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // Schedule the next screenshot after 1 minute
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60000); // 60,000 milliseconds = 1 minute
            }
        }
    }, 60000);
    mWebView.loadUrl("URL");
}`
```

Issue : its running the APK fine for few hours or maybe few days as well on Android TV but after 36 hours or maybe 24+ hours it automatically close. not sure why its happening and i also dont have logs of error as this is unexpectedly happening.

I tried to run on other TV's as well and same behaviours on those aswell.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).